# Arreglo que cuente la cantidad de divisores no funciona podrían revisar todo mi codigo y solucionarlo

Tags: bluej

intente crear un arreglo que cuente la cantidad de divisores pero tengo problemas en el codigo de cantidad de divisores.

```
    private int[] vector;
    private int tamano;
    public maquinaVectores()
    {
        
    }
```

en esta parte el programa pide el tamaño del vector y los numeros.

```
 public void cargarVector()
       {
            int indice;
            Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("ingrese tamano del vector");
            tamano=leer.nextInt();
            vector= new int[tamano];
            for(indice=0;indice<tamano;indice++)
            {
                System.out.println("ingrese un dato para el vector");
                vector[indice]=leer.nextInt();
            }
             System.out.println("cargado finalizado");
       }
                     
    
               > en esta parte el programa pide el tamaño del vector y los numeros imprimiendolos en pantalla
```

** Esto es un codigo en bluej**           
2. Esto es un elemento de un arreglo                        
en esta parte final es la que tengo problemas.               
con el código al tratar de encontrar la cantidad divisores.

```
 public int calcularCantidadDivisores()
       {
           int residuo, canDiv, indice;
           canDiv=0;
           for(indice=1;indice<=vector[indice];indice++)
            {
                residuo= tamano%vector[indice];
                if(residuo==0)
                {
                    canDiv=canDiv+1;
                }
            
            }
           return canDiv;
       }
```

en esta parte final es la que tengo problemas.               
con el código al tratar de encontrar la cantidad divisores sale error en la fórmula for una ayuda porfa no se como hacer que funcione.

Comment: No me ayuda me ayudaría mucho si alguien reescribe el código para que funcione